# How to modify html tag using javascript to add a target _blank

Tags: javascript, append, target

I have the following link:

```
x = <a href="https://t.co/LwlI7i81">https://t.co/LwlI7i81</a>
```

how can I use javascript to modify the url, to add a target _blank?

```
 String.prototype.parseURL = function() {
        return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&~\?\/.=]+/g, function(url) {
          console.log(url.link(url))
            return url.link(url);           
        });
    };
```

Comment: Either you are using [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/E4X) (which appears to be effectively dead) or that isn't your actual code. Which is it? If the latter, please fix it. It would be helpful for more context. Are you really dealing with a string containing HTML rather then a DOM?

Comment: how do I do this the dead way?

Comment: The dead way? Are you saying that you *are* using E4X?

Comment: `target="_blank"` has nothing to do with the URL though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can extract the element from the DOM that you want (i.e. the link itself) then you can simply call `myLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');`

Note that this will not work with the raw HTML assigned to a variable as a string.